# Difficulty in solving a polynomial

Tags: equation-solving

```
k1 = 0.01;
k2 - 0.01;
k3 = 0.01;
R = {{-317074. - 3255.08 k1 - 6510.16 k2 + 39.25 b^2, -241517. - 
     4593.15 k1 - 5295.88 k2 + 29.897 b^2, -7.25817*10^-7 + 
     4603.38 k1 - 3.69363*10^-9 k2 - 1.12278*10^-11 b^2, -10161.8 - 
     409.588 k1 + 0.397884 k2 + 1.25525 b^2, 
    126793. - 9.34595*10^-9 k1 + 2780.26 k2 - 15.6955 b^2, 
    64244.2 - 1.90887*10^-8 k1 + 2574.91 k2 - 7.95115 b^2, -10781.2 - 
     1.8725*10^-9 k1 + 0.292511 k2 + 1.33767 b^2, -2.07898 - 
     7.30152*10^-12 k1 + 0.00825368 k2 + 0.0000109055 b^2, -76688.6 + 
     3977.98 k1 - 7007.88 k2 + 9.49819 b^2, -9234.46 - 185.204 k1 + 
     0.0237841 k2 + 1.14341 b^2, 
    22001. - 2.12083*10^-8 k1 + 2009.06 k2 - 2.72346 b^2, 
    65.6162 - 8.03025*10^-10 k1 - 0.610304 k2 + 
     0.00145184 b^2}, {-241517. - 4593.15 k1 - 5295.88 k2 + 
     29.897 b^2, -1.49882*10^6 - 6481.27 k1 - 4308.09 k2 + 
     32.4507 b^2, 
    2.50722*10^6 + 6495.7 k1 - 3.00469*10^-9 k2 - 
     19.3977 b^2, -81891.2 - 577.959 k1 + 0.32367 k2 + 
     1.77261 b^2, -522099. - 1.31878*10^-8 k1 + 2261.69 k2 - 
     6.9699 b^2, 
    295696. - 2.69355*10^-8 k1 + 2094.64 k2 - 6.40372 b^2, 
    151362. - 2.64224*10^-9 k1 + 0.237952 k2 + 
     0.0314201 b^2, -5.60481 - 1.0303*10^-11 k1 + 0.0067142 k2 + 
     0.0000107143 b^2, 
    107.591 + 5613.22 k1 - 5700.77 k2 - 0.00126411 b^2, 
    26886.8 - 261.336 k1 + 0.0193479 k2 + 0.821086 b^2, 
    631401. - 2.99265*10^-8 k1 + 1634.33 k2 - 5.02847 b^2, -638.944 - 
     1.13313*10^-9 k1 - 0.49647 k2 + 
     0.00477873 b^2}, {-7.25817*10^-7 + 4603.38 k1 - 
     3.69363*10^-9 k2 - 1.12278*10^-11 b^2, 
    2.50722*10^6 + 6495.7 k1 - 3.00469*10^-9 k2 - 
     19.3977 b^2, -5.07318*10^6 - 6510.16 k1 - 2.09563*10^-21 k2 + 
     39.25 b^2, 
    227898. + 579.246 k1 + 2.25745*10^-13 k2 - 1.76248 b^2, 
    1.31625*10^6 + 1.32172*10^-8 k1 + 1.57742*10^-9 k2 - 
     10.1835 b^2, -31.4777 + 2.69954*10^-8 k1 + 1.46091*10^-9 k2 + 
     0.000244454 b^2, -243037. + 2.64812*10^-9 k1 + 
     1.6596*10^-13 k2 + 1.88102 b^2, 
    13.4875 + 1.03259*10^-11 k1 + 4.68284*10^-15 k2 - 
     0.0000171871 b^2, -2.29463*10^6 - 5625.71 k1 - 
     3.97602*10^-9 k2 + 17.7514 b^2, 
    29.4428 + 261.918 k1 + 1.34942*10^-14 k2 - 
     0.00009334 b^2, -657764. + 2.99931*10^-8 k1 + 1.13987*10^-9 k2 + 
     5.08896 b^2, 
    754.94 + 1.13565*10^-9 k1 - 3.46264*10^-13 k2 + 
     0.000759213 b^2}, {-10161.8 - 409.588 k1 + 0.397884 k2 + 
     1.25525 b^2, -81891.2 - 577.959 k1 + 0.32367 k2 + 1.77261 b^2, 
    227898. + 579.246 k1 + 2.25745*10^-13 k2 - 
     1.76248 b^2, -33454.3 - 51.5388 k1 - 0.0000243176 k2 + 
     0.152106 b^2, -74564.1 - 1.17601*10^-9 k1 - 0.169922 k2 - 
     0.0160892 b^2, -139509. - 2.40194*10^-9 k1 - 0.157372 k2 - 
     0.0454974 b^2, -13622.5 - 2.35618*10^-10 k1 - 0.0000178775 k2 - 
     0.006816 b^2, -13564.5 - 9.18755*10^-13 k1 - 5.04443*10^-7 k2 + 
     0.00780019 b^2, 
    718940. + 500.551 k1 + 0.428303 k2 - 1.41795 b^2, -21055.3 - 
     23.3043 k1 - 1.45362*10^-6 k2 + 0.0666351 b^2, -145331. - 
     2.66865*10^-9 k1 - 0.122789 k2 - 0.0507012 b^2, 
    613.183 - 1.01045*10^-10 k1 + 0.0000373002 k2 - 
     0.00251461 b^2}, {126793. - 9.34595*10^-9 k1 + 2780.26 k2 - 
     15.6955 b^2, -522099. - 1.31878*10^-8 k1 + 2261.69 k2 - 
     6.9699 b^2, 
    1.31625*10^6 + 1.32172*10^-8 k1 + 1.57742*10^-9 k2 - 
     10.1835 b^2, -74564.1 - 1.17601*10^-9 k1 - 0.169922 k2 - 
     0.0160892 b^2, -413088. - 2.6834*10^-20 k1 - 1187.35 k2 + 
     8.94374 b^2, -155164. - 5.48072*10^-20 k1 - 1099.65 k2 + 
     3.36173 b^2, 
    45802.1 - 5.37631*10^-21 k1 - 0.124921 k2 - 
     0.992499 b^2, -31.3605 - 2.09641*10^-23 k1 - 0.00352486 k2 + 
     0.0000116161 b^2, 
    1.15636*10^6 + 1.14215*10^-8 k1 + 2992.82 k2 - 
     9.20781 b^2, -14130.2 - 5.31756*10^-10 k1 - 0.0101574 k2 - 
     0.431012 b^2, 
    2.37586 - 6.08931*10^-20 k1 - 858.001 k2 - 
     8.16204*10^-7 b^2, -108.193 - 2.30564*10^-21 k1 + 0.260639 k2 - 
     0.00288933 b^2}, {64244.2 - 1.90887*10^-8 k1 + 2574.91 k2 - 
     7.95115 b^2, 
    295696. - 2.69355*10^-8 k1 + 2094.64 k2 - 6.40372 b^2, -31.4777 + 
     2.69954*10^-8 k1 + 1.46091*10^-9 k2 + 
     0.000244454 b^2, -139509. - 2.40194*10^-9 k1 - 0.157372 k2 - 
     0.0454974 b^2, -155164. - 5.48072*10^-20 k1 - 1099.65 k2 + 
     3.36173 b^2, -926805. - 1.11941*10^-19 k1 - 1018.43 k2 + 
     2.94103 b^2, -148344. - 1.09809*10^-20 k1 - 0.115695 k2 - 
     0.0490629 b^2, 
    8524.49 - 4.28181*10^-23 k1 - 0.00326451 k2 - 0.00548197 b^2, 
    3.95654*10^6 + 2.33279*10^-8 k1 + 2771.77 k2 - 
     7.81479 b^2, -126243. - 1.08609*10^-9 k1 - 0.00940712 k2 - 
     0.0403184 b^2, -1.134*10^6 - 1.24371*10^-19 k1 - 794.628 k2 + 
     2.24037 b^2, 
    5341.79 - 4.70916*10^-21 k1 + 0.241388 k2 - 
     0.016643 b^2}, {-10781.2 - 1.8725*10^-9 k1 + 0.292511 k2 + 
     1.33767 b^2, 
    151362. - 2.64224*10^-9 k1 + 0.237952 k2 + 
     0.0314201 b^2, -243037. + 2.64812*10^-9 k1 + 1.6596*10^-13 k2 + 
     1.88102 b^2, -13622.5 - 2.35618*10^-10 k1 - 0.0000178775 k2 - 
     0.006816 b^2, 
    45802.1 - 5.37631*10^-21 k1 - 0.124921 k2 - 
     0.992499 b^2, -148344. - 1.09809*10^-20 k1 - 0.115695 k2 - 
     0.0490629 b^2, -37896.2 - 1.07717*10^-21 k1 - 0.000013143 k2 + 
     0.172808 b^2, -248.398 - 4.20024*10^-24 k1 - 3.70851*10^-7 k2 + 
     0.00116987 b^2, 
    537479. + 2.28835*10^-9 k1 + 0.314875 k2 + 
     0.192445 b^2, -22369.3 - 1.0654*10^-10 k1 - 1.06866*10^-6 k2 + 
     0.0709145 b^2, -219083. - 1.22002*10^-20 k1 - 0.0902704 k2 + 
     0.432727 b^2, 
    651.855 - 4.61945*10^-22 k1 + 0.0000274219 k2 - 
     0.00258701 b^2}, {-2.07898 - 7.30152*10^-12 k1 + 0.00825368 k2 + 
     0.0000109055 b^2, -5.60481 - 1.0303*10^-11 k1 + 0.0067142 k2 + 
     0.0000107143 b^2, 
    13.4875 + 1.03259*10^-11 k1 + 4.68284*10^-15 k2 - 
     0.0000171871 b^2, -13564.5 - 9.18755*10^-13 k1 - 
     5.04443*10^-7 k2 + 0.00780019 b^2, -31.3605 - 
     2.09641*10^-23 k1 - 0.00352486 k2 + 0.0000116161 b^2, 
    8524.49 - 4.28181*10^-23 k1 - 0.00326451 k2 - 
     0.00548197 b^2, -248.398 - 4.20024*10^-24 k1 - 
     3.70851*10^-7 k2 + 0.00116987 b^2, -8.11709*10^7 - 
     1.63782*10^-26 k1 - 1.04641*10^-8 k2 + 39.25 b^2, 
    9474.45 + 8.92308*10^-12 k1 + 0.0088847 k2 - 
     0.00562637 b^2, -44.0457 - 4.15435*10^-13 k1 - 
     3.01538*10^-8 k2 + 0.000136984 b^2, -58.9499 - 
     4.75727*10^-23 k1 - 0.00254712 k2 + 0.0000461921 b^2, 
    12987.1 - 1.80128*10^-24 k1 + 7.73752*10^-7 k2 - 
     0.00461317 b^2}, {-76688.6 + 3977.98 k1 - 7007.88 k2 + 
     9.49819 b^2, 
    107.591 + 5613.22 k1 - 5700.77 k2 - 
     0.00126411 b^2, -2.29463*10^6 - 5625.71 k1 - 3.97602*10^-9 k2 + 
     17.7514 b^2, 718940. + 500.551 k1 + 0.428303 k2 - 1.41795 b^2, 
    1.15636*10^6 + 1.14215*10^-8 k1 + 2992.82 k2 - 9.20781 b^2, 
    3.95654*10^6 + 2.33279*10^-8 k1 + 2771.77 k2 - 7.81479 b^2, 
    537479. + 2.28835*10^-9 k1 + 0.314875 k2 + 0.192445 b^2, 
    9474.45 + 8.92308*10^-12 k1 + 0.0088847 k2 - 
     0.00562637 b^2, -1.84704*10^7 - 4861.42 k1 - 7543.66 k2 + 
     36.4663 b^2, 558416. + 226.335 k1 + 0.0256025 k2 - 0.570828 b^2, 
    4.6185*10^6 + 2.59183*10^-8 k1 + 2162.66 k2 - 
     5.84389 b^2, -38916.3 + 9.81364*10^-10 k1 - 0.656963 k2 + 
     0.0762635 b^2}, {-9234.46 - 185.204 k1 + 0.0237841 k2 + 
     1.14341 b^2, 26886.8 - 261.336 k1 + 0.0193479 k2 + 0.821086 b^2, 
    29.4428 + 261.918 k1 + 1.34942*10^-14 k2 - 
     0.00009334 b^2, -21055.3 - 23.3043 k1 - 1.45362*10^-6 k2 + 
     0.0666351 b^2, -14130.2 - 5.31756*10^-10 k1 - 0.0101574 k2 - 
     0.431012 b^2, -126243. - 1.08609*10^-9 k1 - 0.00940712 k2 - 
     0.0403184 b^2, -22369.3 - 1.0654*10^-10 k1 - 1.06866*10^-6 k2 + 
     0.0709145 b^2, -44.0457 - 4.15435*10^-13 k1 - 3.01538*10^-8 k2 + 
     0.000136984 b^2, 
    558416. + 226.335 k1 + 0.0256025 k2 - 0.570828 b^2, -19197.2 - 
     10.5375 k1 - 8.68923*10^-8 k2 + 0.0608603 b^2, -160055. - 
     1.20669*10^-9 k1 - 0.00733987 k2 + 0.163588 b^2, 
    767.742 - 4.56897*10^-11 k1 + 2.22967*10^-6 k2 - 
     0.00230975 b^2}, {22001. - 2.12083*10^-8 k1 + 2009.06 k2 - 
     2.72346 b^2, 
    631401. - 2.99265*10^-8 k1 + 1634.33 k2 - 5.02847 b^2, -657764. + 
     2.99931*10^-8 k1 + 1.13987*10^-9 k2 + 5.08896 b^2, -145331. - 
     2.66865*10^-9 k1 - 0.122789 k2 - 0.0507012 b^2, 
    2.37586 - 6.08931*10^-20 k1 - 858.001 k2 - 
     8.16204*10^-7 b^2, -1.134*10^6 - 1.24371*10^-19 k1 - 
     794.628 k2 + 2.24037 b^2, -219083. - 1.22002*10^-20 k1 - 
     0.0902704 k2 + 0.432727 b^2, -58.9499 - 4.75727*10^-23 k1 - 
     0.00254712 k2 + 0.0000461921 b^2, 
    4.6185*10^6 + 2.59183*10^-8 k1 + 2162.66 k2 - 
     5.84389 b^2, -160055. - 1.20669*10^-9 k1 - 0.00733987 k2 + 
     0.163588 b^2, -1.51759*10^6 - 1.38182*10^-19 k1 - 620.006 k2 + 
     2.99673 b^2, 
    11219.2 - 5.23207*10^-21 k1 + 0.188342 k2 - 
     0.0216322 b^2}, {65.6162 - 8.03025*10^-10 k1 - 0.610304 k2 + 
     0.00145184 b^2, -638.944 - 1.13313*10^-9 k1 - 0.49647 k2 + 
     0.00477873 b^2, 
    754.94 + 1.13565*10^-9 k1 - 3.46264*10^-13 k2 + 0.000759213 b^2, 
    613.183 - 1.01045*10^-10 k1 + 0.0000373002 k2 - 
     0.00251461 b^2, -108.193 - 2.30564*10^-21 k1 + 0.260639 k2 - 
     0.00288933 b^2, 
    5341.79 - 4.70916*10^-21 k1 + 0.241388 k2 - 0.016643 b^2, 
    651.855 - 4.61945*10^-22 k1 + 0.0000274219 k2 - 0.00258701 b^2, 
    12987.1 - 1.80128*10^-24 k1 + 7.73752*10^-7 k2 - 
     0.00461317 b^2, -38916.3 + 9.81364*10^-10 k1 - 0.656963 k2 + 
     0.0762635 b^2, 
    767.742 - 4.56897*10^-11 k1 + 2.22967*10^-6 k2 - 0.00230975 b^2, 
    11219.2 - 5.23207*10^-21 k1 + 0.188342 k2 - 
     0.0216322 b^2, -1249.8 - 1.98106*10^-22 k1 - 0.0000572138 k2 + 
     0.000444287 b^2}};
MatrixForm[R]
P = Simplify[Det[R]]
NSolve[{P == 0, 0 < b < 100000000}, b]
```

I have a 12 cross 12 system, I have taken the determinant, the determinant function depends on one single variable `b`. Now I am trying to find the roots of that `det` function. `NSolve` is taking too much of time. what is the best way to find the roots.

Comment: There is `k2 - 0.01;` rather than `k2=0.01`. This difference will have a big impact on speed. Even with this fixed, exact arithmetic is likely to make it much easier (as noted in a response by @kglr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use exact numbers:

```
k1 = 1/100; k2 = 1/100; k3 = 1/100;
R = Rationalize[R, 10^(-12)];
P = Simplify[Det[R]];

NSolve[{P == 0, 0 < b < 100000000}, b] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0065, {{b -> 89.947}, {b -> 182.335}, {b -> 360.493}, {b -> 
>           806.155}, {b -> 2248.09}, {b -> 3328.64}, {b -> 4776.58}, {b -> 
>           19070.2}}}